# Certain web pages showing incorrectly

Tags: website

https://s24.postimg.org/urwtnq639/Untitled.png
https://s24.postimg.org/5zx7ghowl/gfdfgdfgd.png
So far I've found those to be broken. Everything worked fine prior so I really have no clue. Tried with and without AdBlock and antivirus programs, cleared browsing data, reinstalled Windows without deleting apps and data, scanned with MalwareBytes, Norton and AdwCleaner, checked for weird processes in Task Manager and/or recent installations, tried with different browsers and reinstalled Chrome... I'm out of ideas. At least it's keeping me from wasting time on YouTube...

Comment: Are any other devices in this network affected? Can you try to use another network?

Comment: First screen shows that CSS styles are not loaded. Second seems to be no JavaScript. It seems that only main HTML is loaded.

Comment: Does your computer have an IPv6 address or IPv6 default route? Sometimes parts of a page are loaded through IPv4, which works fine, but IPv6 might be not working properly, resulting in timeouts.

Comment: @gronostaj I tried from my phone hotspot and it's the same thing. There are also 2 more users connected to the network I'm using and they have no such problems.

Comment: @mtak Tried http://test-ipv6.com/ and it gave me:
Your browser has real working IPv6 address - but is avoiding using it. We're concerned about this.